# How to deal with channels / "blocking" operations in Go?

Tags: go

I am playing around with golang, and want to write an app that starts an http server that serves some content, and the content is updated from another app through a message queue.

The problem I am facing is on listening to the queue and starting the server, both things seem to block, and I am not quite sure if my current solution is right.

If I write it like this, then the server will never start

```
    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()
    <-forever

    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), t.handler)
```

If I write it like this, then the app will never start listening to the queue

```
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), t.handler)

    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()
    <-forever
```

So my current solution is to put the ListenAndServer inside the forever block, which seems to work, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do

```golang
    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), t.handler)
    <-forever
```

Comment: What is the point of the `forever` channel?

Comment: 2nd way is fine. `ListenAndServe` blocks for the lifetime of the server, so as @BurakSerdar notes `forever` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `<-forever` creates a deadlock since nothing will be placed on it.
`http.ListenAndServe` is blocking (think of it as firing up an event loop), so if you want to run it to not block the main goroutine (which is not recommended), you can call it from another goroutine.

`<-forever` line blocks everything because it won't receive anything.

If you want your channels to be non-blocking, you must use buffered channels. but you have to make sure that you read it properly.

```
// replace interface{} with your own type

func readContent (msg <-chan interface{}, toHandler chan<- interface{} , ...args){
      // your handler func
      for d := range msg{
          toHandler <- d
      }       
      // rest of function
}

// with closure. you can do it with struct properties also
func messageHandler(msg <-chan interfcae{}) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
         message := make ([]interface{},0)
         for d := range msg {
            message = append (message, d)
         }
         // send it to  the client
         w.Write([]byte(message)
    })
}



// inside main routine
// 
// do your own work without <-forever
// Listen and serve will open a new Goroutine for each client request
http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), t.handler)
```